# Why is my UI not refreshing after setState()? (using React and Rails)

Tags: reactjs

I'm in the process of learning React and in need of some help. When calling `setState()` in my `handleNewRecord()` event, my UI does not refresh. The data is all being pushed into the database successfully, but only visible after refreshing my page manually. Hopefully someone can help me out... It's been about 3 days now with the same problem. here are my components...

Records (Parent)

```
class Records extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        records: []
    }

    this.handleNewRecord = this.handleNewRecord.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        records: this.props.records
    })
}

 handleNewRecord(record) {
     console.log(this.state)
     const newState = this.props.records.slice();
     console.log(newState)
     newState.push(record)
     console.log(newState)
     this.setState({
         records: newState
     })
}


render() { 
    const records = this.props.records.map((record) =>
                            <Record record={record} key={record.id} />
                            )
                            return (
                                <div className="container">
                                    <h1>Records</h1>
                                    <RecordForm handleNewRecord={this.handleNewRecord}/>
                                    <table className="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Date</th>
                                                <th>Title</th>
                                                <th>Amount</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                          {records}
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            )   
  }     
}
```

single Record (child)

```
class Record extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

}

render() {
    return(
        <tr>
            <td>{this.props.record.date}</td>
            <td>{this.props.record.title}</td>
            <td>{this.props.record.amount}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
}
```

Record Form (child)

```
class RecordForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
            record: {
                title: '',
                amount: '',
                date: ''
            }
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

}

handleChange(e) {
var key = e.target.name
var val = e.target.value
var obj  = this.state.record
obj[key] = val
this.setState(obj)
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    var that = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            record: this.state.record,
        },
        url: '/records',
        success: function(res) {
            that.props.handleNewRecord(res)
            that.setState({
                record: {
                title: '',
                amount: '',
                date: ''
            }
            })
        },
    })
    console.log('submitted');
}

render () {
return (
            <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="date" type="text" name="date" value={this.state.record.date} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="title" type="text" name="title" value={this.state.record.title} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="amount"  type="text" name="amount" value={this.state.record.amount} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit" >Create Record</button><br />
                    </label>
                </div>
            </form>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your render function reads `this.props.records`, but you're not updating props, you're updating state. Read from `this.state.records` instead.

```
render() {
    const records = this.state.records.map((record) =>
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks Andy... thats exactly what it was.

Comment: The simple errors are the most insidious ones to debug!

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing records as props then
there is no need to set it in the component's state. 
Pass a callback function as prop which will set the container's state.

```
handleNewRecord(record)  {
 this.props.somefunction(record)
```

}

And from wherever you are calling is Parent component i.e. Records,  there should be a function like,

```
somefunction(record) {
Record =   this.state.record.slice()
Record.append(record) 
this.setState(record)
```

}